# why modifiying private data results in firing onUnmount?

Tags: vue.js

i would like to know please why when i change, for an example, the value of `name_`, the lifecycle call-backs mentioned in the screen-shot gets called accordingly.
Actually, what i expected out of changing the `name_` is it results in an invokation to `onBeforeUpdate` and `onUpdated`

please explain to me why this behaviour is happenning

**App.vue**:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    const name_ = "ertz"
    const address_ = "aasf"
    const phone_ = "100 xx 50"
    return{
      name_,
      address_,
      phone_
    }
  }
};
</script>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { onBeforeMount,onMounted,onUpdated,onBeforeUpdate,onActivated,onDeactivated,onBeforeUnmount,onUnmounted } from 'vue'

onBeforeMount(()=>{
  console.log("onBeforeMount");
})
onMounted(()=>{
  console.log("onMounted");
})

onBeforeUpdate(()=>{
  console.log("onBeforeUpdate");
})
onUpdated(()=>{
  console.log("onUpdated");
})

onActivated(()=>{
  console.log("onActivated");
})
onDeactivated(()=>{
  console.log("onDeactivated");
})

onBeforeUnmount(()=>{
  console.log("onBeforeUnmount");
})
onUnmounted(()=>{
  console.log("onUnmounted");
})

</script>
```

**img**

[image]

Comment: Do you change your variable in a some method that called by any event or programmatically in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change a variable programmatically in your code when you have your app is started in dev env with hot-reload, a changed component will be re-rendered (it will be unmounted and mounted again).

But if you change a variable "in a natural way" for example in a some method that called by any event (by button click) a component will not be unmounted but just updated.

**For example, try to add a button that changes the variable and see what lifecycle events will be called:**

```
<button @click="name_ = name_ + ' changed'">CLICK</button>
```